# Closure compiler source map = empty (Chrome) or wrong (Firefox) code window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, google-closure-compiler, source-maps, firefox-developer-tools

I have a set of JavaScript files in '*src*' folder compiled by Closure Compiler in a single file *cw-around.js* in '*src/comp*' with generated source maps *cw-around.js.map* also in '*src/comp*'.

"//# sourceMappingURL=xxx" is at the end of the compiled file *cw-around.js*.
xxx being a full HTTP link (local web server) to *cw-around.js.map* and being successfully tested in a browser.
{"version":3,"file":"cw-around.js" is the beginning of the *cw-around.js.map* file

In the Dev mode/sources file list, I can see the associated files in Chrome and Firefox (when I put a wrong xxx, I can see only the compiled *cw-around.js* file).

There, when I double click on an associated file (*cw-demodata.js*, one of the JavaScript file name that was included in the compiled file):

1. **In Chrome 58 or 61** ("JavaScript source maps enabled" + "source map detected"), **an empty code window is displayed**.
   [image: screen capture in Chrome (Windows 10)]
2. **In Firefox 54** ("show original sources" + "devtools.source-map.locations.enabled;true"), **the HTML code of my calling web page is displayed**.
   [image: screen capture in Firefox (Windows 10)]

What's wrong? How to investigate to identify what's wrong?

Comment: Sounds like browser bugs, but without being able to see or reproduce it, can't say for sure.

Comment: same bug in 3 different browsers? seems not very likely

Comment: You description sounds different for each browser, not the same.

Comment: What OS are you using? Please make a screen movie of what you are doing and add it to your question. In Windows or OSX you can use [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/).

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and I added 2 screen shots to the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue: to compile the js files and generate the source map in the same directory as the js files. The associated js files are now properly displayed in both Chrome and Firefox.

Previously, after successfully opening the compiled js file and the source map, it seems that the browser was unable to find and load the non compiled js files.
It would have been great to have an error message in the console to quickly spot the problem...

Answer (score 2):

I just had the very same issue, and it came from `sourceMapLocationMappings` not correctly set. In the source map, there is (alongside `"version"` and `"file"`) a `"sources": []` entry, that tells the browser where the actual source file (not the source map) is to be found.

As I, like you, compiled the assets from a subfolder, the subfolder path was inside this sources array (i.e. it was `"sources": ["src/comp/foo.js"]` instead of `"sources": ["foo.js"]`). The browser tried to request `src/comp/foo.js` from my webserver, and it obviously wasn't there, because `foo.js` was there directly.

The solution to this is to set up proper `sourceMapLocationMappings`. Using the closure-compiler cli, you do that with [`--source_map_location_mapping "\"src/comp/foo.js^|foo.js\""`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/bf351b9f099e55e2c6405d73b22aaee8924c6f87/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java#L338-L341). Using the ant task, you add a [`sourceMapLocaionMapping="src/comp/foo.js|foo.js"`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/ant/CompileTask.java#L770-L772) to the task call.

This adjusts the `"sources"` to point to `["foo.js"]` directly, which is then served by your webserver and can be found by the dev tools.

Edit: added double quotes in `--source_map_location_mapping` according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/29542669